# Multer fileFilter is not working (it does not returns the 404 error status)

Tags: node.js, image, upload, multer

This is my file with Multer configs

```
module.exports = (multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, './public/upload/especies')
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString() + "_" + file.originalname)
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
            console.log('false')
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        console.log('true')
        return cb(null, true);
    }
}))
```

Then i call this file config as a middleware inside the upload images router

```
const router = express.Router();

const uploadImg = require("../middlewares/UploadImageEspecie");

router.post("/uploadImg", uploadImg.array('images', 12), async (req, res) => {
    if (req.files) {
        console.log(req.files)
        return res.json({
            error: false,
            message: "Upload realizado com sucesso!"
        })
    }
    else {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: true,
            message: 'Erro: Upload não realizado com sucesso, necessário enviar imagens no formato PNG, JPG ou JPEG.'
        })
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

But, for some reason, when I try to upload some files with .mp4 or .psd extensions it does not returns the error 404 status, and also prints the console.log false. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function in multer's filter, the first parameter should be an instance of an Error like `new Error('Invalid file format')`

```js
module.exports = (multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, './public/upload/especies')
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, Date.now().toString() + "_" + file.originalname)
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
            console.log('false')
            return cb(new Error('Invalid file format'), false);
        }
        console.log('true')
        return cb(null, true);
    }
}))
```